# How to locate the Android Emulator process that consumes all cpu resources?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb, ubuntu-14.04

Since I have updated Android Studio to version 1.2.1.1 all of the same emulators i usually use for making app consume suddenly about 100 % cpu power continuously until I close the emulators.

It doesn't even help reducing cpu usage temporarily after killing some of the processes of emulator etc. They tend to restart automatically again after a short while.

Below i have included the output of `top` and `./adb shell ps` commands.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 5806 torsh     20   0 4406304 939516  18300 R 100.1 11.8  12:52.27 emulator64-x86
 1715 torsh      9 -11  496648   8872   7452 S   1.3  0.1   1:25.90 pulseaudio
 2142 torsh     20   0 4558528 1.116g  22580 S   0.7 14.7  17:34.35 java
 1133 root      20   0  280576  38408  23288 S   0.3  0.5   2:20.39 Xorg
 1617 torsh     20   0  740932  25868  22176 S   0.3  0.3   0:18.05 lxpanel
 5288 torsh     20   0   31548   5036   2728 S   0.3  0.1   0:04.23 adb
 6048 torsh     20   0  695856  23240  19592 S   0.3  0.3   0:00.38 lxterminal
 6071 torsh     20   0   29152   2992   2484 R   0.3  0.0   0:00.25 top
    1 root      20   0   33904   3664   2560 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.45 init
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 kthreadd

~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ ./adb shell ps
USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC        NAME
root      1     0     9128   604   810e3667 0042439a S /init
root      2     0     0      0     81043613 00000000 S kthreadd
root      3     2     0      0     81048fed 00000000 S ksoftirqd/0
root      4     2     0      0     8103ea19 00000000 S kworker/0:0
root      5     2     0      0     8103ea19 00000000 S kworker/0:0H
root      7     2     0      0     8107b9a9 00000000 S rcu_preempt
root      8     2     0      0     8107b69e 00000000 S rcu_bh
root      9     2     0      0     8107b69e 00000000 S rcu_sched
root      10    2     0      0     8103e70d 00000000 S khelper
root      242   2     0      0     8103e70d 00000000 S writeback
root      244   2     0      0     8103e70d 00000000 S bioset
root      246   2     0      0     8103e70d 00000000 S kblockd
root      254   2     0      0     8103e70d 00000000 S ata_sff
root      265   2     0      0     813535a5 00000000 S khubd
root      273   2     0      0     8103e70d 00000000 S md
root      287   2     0      0     8103e70d 00000000 S cfg80211
root      390   2     0      0     810aa789 00000000 S kswapd0
root      454   2     0      0     81108d96 00000000 S fsnotify_mark
root      473   2     0      0     8103e70d 00000000 S crypto
root      566   2     0      0     8103e70d 00000000 S iscsi_eh
root      639   2     0      0     8103e70d 00000000 S binder
root      657   2     0      0     8103ea19 00000000 S kworker/0:2
root      678   2     0      0     8103e70d 00000000 S deferwq
root      680   2     0      0     8103ea19 00000000 S kworker/u2:2
root      681   1     9120   480   810e3667 0042439a S /sbin/ueventd
root      901   2     0      0     8103ea19 00000000 S kworker/0:1H
root      902   2     0      0     8117809b 00000000 S jbd2/mtdblock0-
root      903   2     0      0     8103e70d 00000000 S ext4-dio-unwrit
root      911   2     0      0     8103ea19 00000000 S kworker/u2:3
root      915   2     0      0     813c3ff5 00000000 S mmcqd/0
root      925   2     0      0     8117809b 00000000 S jbd2/mtdblock1-
root      926   2     0      0     8103e70d 00000000 S ext4-dio-unwrit
root      930   2     0      0     8117809b 00000000 S jbd2/mtdblock2-
root      931   2     0      0     8103e70d 00000000 S ext4-dio-unwrit
logd      932   1     16208  2824  ffffffff 26c9aa37 S /system/bin/logd
root      933   1     10136  496   8110c261 0044735a S /sbin/healthd
root      934   1     12328  1664  8110c261 79e0295a S /system/bin/lmkd
system    935   1     10204  864   813e089c 4892d3b7 S /system/bin/servicemanager
root      936   1     16184  2720  ffffffff 1a07fa57 S /system/bin/vold
system    937   1     65132  4460  ffffffff 4c22795a S /system/bin/surfaceflinger
root      939   1     9924   764   8110c261 ba4a195a S /system/bin/qemud
root      942   1     14268  536   ffffffff 004243ea S /sbin/adbd
root      943   1     20204  1904  ffffffff 3f06da57 S /system/bin/netd
root      944   1     10884  1064  813f581c f76d2683 S /system/bin/debuggerd
root      945   1     11084  1224  813f581c b85b5b1a S /system/bin/debuggerd64
radio     946   1     15736  1920  ffffffff 3f5e9a57 S /system/bin/rild
drm       947   1     21996  3928  ffffffff f76ebb16 S /system/bin/drmserver
install   949   1     10216  916   8147a3c7 e4821ad7 S /system/bin/installd
keystore  950   1     14616  2752  813e089c df47f3b7 S /system/bin/keystore
root      951   1     574744 55628 ffffffff cf81fc7a S zygote64
root      952   1     546212 48512 ffffffff f7501fe5 S zygote
root      959   2     0      0     8106d1a8 00000000 S kauditd
system    1286  951   696920 90548 ffffffff cf82095a S system_server
u0_a12    1374  951   641776 79948 ffffffff cf82095a S com.android.systemui
u0_a30    1444  951   595368 39128 ffffffff cf82095a S com.android.inputmethod.latin
u0_a5     1503  951   583560 35196 ffffffff cf82095a S android.process.media
radio     1547  951   604932 44680 ffffffff cf82095a S com.android.phone
u0_a39    1611  951   583052 27968 ffffffff cf82095a S com.android.printspooler
u0_a2     1632  951   585400 35500 ffffffff cf82095a S android.process.acore
u0_a21    1699  951   584772 31764 ffffffff cf82095a S com.android.deskclock
u0_a17    1733  951   589416 31192 ffffffff cf82095a S com.android.calendar
u0_a1     1757  951   582456 31636 ffffffff cf82095a S com.android.providers.calendar
system    1803  951   581088 29288 ffffffff cf82095a S com.android.keychain
u0_a4     1820  951   586960 28336 ffffffff cf82095a S com.android.dialer
u0_a8     1854  951   581212 26776 ffffffff cf82095a S com.android.managedprovisioning
u0_a9     1872  951   589304 32664 ffffffff cf82095a S com.android.mms
system    1900  951   592384 28228 ffffffff cf82095a S com.android.settings
u0_a25    1930  951   596704 36140 ffffffff cf82095a S com.android.email
u0_a27    1950  951   588092 29492 ffffffff cf82095a S com.android.exchange
root      1993  942   9836   908   813f581c 00bb4eda S logcat
u0_a3     2021  951   579980 27356 ffffffff cf82095a S com.android.defcontainer
u0_a38    2057  951   579988 25728 ffffffff cf82095a S com.svox.pico
u0_a66    2086  951   595416 42684 ffffffff cf82095a S com.example.torsh.myfragmentdialogtest1
media_rw  3650  1     11996  832   ffffffff c1d35ad7 S /system/bin/sdcard
media     3741  1     39052  7452  ffffffff f767db16 S /system/bin/mediaserver
u0_a7     5337  951   618920 66908 ffffffff cf82095a S com.android.launcher
root      9105  942   12264  1472  00000000 78e59ad7 R ps
```